# how to make an open world map for a python game (text based)

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

how would i go about making a open world map in python? this is something i have been troubled by for a long time!.What would be a good technique for me?
heres my code if theres a way for map making thats suitable  for my coding style

```
print "you can write Inventory to see what your weapon is, but in the beta sor far you cant equip weapons!"
JunkJet_Durability = "4"
DAM = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
JunkJet_DAM = "7"
JunkJet_Resistance = "2"
Inventory = JunkJet
Junk = 5
JunkJet_Ammo = 85
print "your locations to go to : RivetCity EverGreenMills  ArcJetLabs Shelter FarragutMetro Citadel RavenRock Vault92 LittleLamplight Vault101 RivetCityLab RivetCityMarket"
vald = raw_input()
print "hey look, i found a note, write Note to see what it says"
Note = "I heard that a place West of evergreen mills called ArcJet Labs.I heard theres a nice weapons stash and even some vault tec works"
print "maybe we should go to arcjet labs! lets go!"
gottoarcjetlabs = "YAY, were going."
dontgo = "NOO, i wanted to go!!,"
if gottoarcjetlabs  ==  True:
    print gottoarcjet
    if dontgo is False:
     dontgo
```

i feel most of the techniques are unsuitable for me? Please help.

Comment: This is considerably too broad a question for SO; take the [tour], learn [ask].

Comment: thanks, ill edit my post!

Comment: will the x o technique be helpful or is it very tedious?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by *"the x o technique"*. This is still far too broad.